# Celery django : launch worker - ImportError: No module named XXX

Tags: python, django, celery

I have difficulties to laucnh celery worker.

The [exemple here](https://github.com/slamer59/Django-Celery-Example) works fine and is closed to documentation.

My problem is that my real configuration folder construction is like this :

```
djangosite/
 |-- package/
 |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |-- laboratory/
 |    |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- migrations/
 |    |    |-- templates/
 |    |    |-- apps.py
 |    |    |-- models.py
 |    |    +-- views.py
 |-- mysite/
 |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |-- settings.py
 |    |-- urls.py
 |    |-- celery.py
 |    +-- wsgi.py
 |-- manage.py
```

My app is a subfolder of package when the exemple show an app in folder.
**__init__** of mysite folder:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**celery.py** contains:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

app = Celery('celery_app')
# This reads, e.g., CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json'] from settings.py:
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# For autodiscover_tasks to work, you must define your tasks in a file called 'tasks.py'.
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print("Request: {0!r}".format(self.request))
```

I launch:
`celery worker -l info -A mysite`

and celery cannot find `laboratory` module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "D:\Developpements\VirtualEnv\laboProd\Scripts\celery.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 793, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 311, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 785, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 717, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\worker.py", line 179, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 274, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\worker.py", line 212, in run
    state_db=self.node_format(state_db, hostname), **kwargs
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.app.loader.init_worker()
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\loaders\base.py", line 128, in init_worker
    self.import_default_modules()
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\loaders\base.py", line 116, in import_default_modules
    signals.import_modules.send(sender=self.app)
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\utils\dispatch\signal.py", line 166, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py", line 73, in on_import_modules
    self.worker_fixup.validate_models()
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py", line 158, in validate_models
    django_setup()
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "d:\developpements\virtualenv\laboprod\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named laboratory
```

How to solve this ? Do I need to put my application the django root folder ?

Comment: Could you give your full error messages?

Comment: where does this "laboratory" thing comes from ? It's not mentionned anywhere in your snippets.

Comment: I edit my question. myapp is called laboratory.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this code for launch the celery : `Celery -A YOURPROJECTNAME worker -l INFO` for the beat schedules : `Celery -A YOURPROJECTNAME worker -b -l INFO`

Comment: In djangosite folder, I run:
`redis-server`, 
`Celery -A YOURPROJECTNAME worker -l INFO` 
`Celery -A YOURPROJECTNAME worker -l INFO -b redis` 
I had redis after -b since expected a broker argument

The same error occurs for both command.